# capturing images while recordin video in qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

I am writing code for a camera application. The application will start to record the video using the camera and while recording it should have an option to capture images also. I'm using QT c++ for programming the application.
I'm able to record the video but how to take capture an images while recording I don't know.

Comment: look at [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html)

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if I got you right, you don't want to capture the whole screen but instead a snap or frame of the video played at any given time....

you can do something like

```
ui->myMovieWidget->grab().save("snap.png");
```

Comment: no actually I'm writing program for a camera app. I want to capture images even while recording a video using the camera